# Poetry using wrong Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-3.8, package-managers

Trying to install packages using poetry
And getting :

```
Current Python version (3.10.4) is not allowed by the project (>=3.8,<3.10).
```

Then I'm trying to do:

```
poetry env use python3.8
```

Or

```
poetry env use 3.8
```

And the same error popping. Any reason this could happen?

Comment: have your activated your env, and then check the version of python in it?

Comment: Probably not, been doing all the time poetry install and don't had any issues before. How can I activate it

Comment: before you can activate env, you need to create it first.
create new env : python -m venv env_name

to activate an env :
env_name/Scripts/activate
then install python 3.8 there

but before to create your new evn, do you have python3.8 or greate installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes I got 3.8.5 and 3.10. I'll try it  soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you are switching python version you are using a full path, so poetry has no problem with resolving the version:

```
poetry env use /usr/bin/python3.8
```

If that didn't help, check your `pyproject.toml` and make sure that the version of python is compatible, something like:

```
python = "^3.8"
```

If that's not the case try setting up global version:

```
pyenv global 3.8.15
```

Also, make sure that all the utility tools are compatible with expected python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev -y
```